How can we export Million records of data from Apache Druid
I want to export millions of records/data from Apache Druid to both csv file and Blob Storage and it should be downloadable.
How can we do it. What approach to follow to export it to csv file and download.
Also What approach to follow to map Blob Storage and store it in form .csv file in Azure
